# Upgrading Craft 2 to 3 hits database error

Tags: craft3, upgrades

I'm working on upgrading a site from Craft2 to Craft3. I've run through the steps in the [upgrade guide](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html#performing-the-upgrade) and when I go to `/admin` and press the button to run the Database upgrade I get the following error.

```
Integrity constraint violation: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'createfoldersinvolume:bb790fdf-3d6b-46b8-a023-b9f7ffe8aba5' for key 'craft_userpermissions_name_unq_idx'
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE craft_userpermissions SET name='createfoldersinvolume:bb790fdf-3d6b-46b8-a023-b9f7ffe8aba5', dateUpdated='2019-02-04 17:39:32' WHERE id=173

Migration: craft\migrations\m180518_173000_permissions_to_uid
```

I can restore the database so that's fine but not sure how best to proceed with the upgrade. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug, you should probably report it directly to support@craftcms.com.

I'm posting this as an answer however, because you may be able to skirt the issue... Try updating to Craft 3.0.x *first*, and then updating the 3.1.x from there.

Comment: Thanks @lindsey-d downgrading to 3.0.x worked, didn't think of trying that. For anyone that has the same issue I updated `composer.json` and changed Craft to `"craftcms/cms": "~3.0.0",` then ran `composer update`.